# Tabbing into Required fields

Tags: c#, wpf

Hoping someone can assist me.

I'm trying to implement tabbing for required fields only. Assuming all required fields implement IRequired.

I was hoping to use TraversalRequest and/or Control.MoveFocus with some sort of Match override to skip any controls which do not implement IRequired.

I can implement the above using VisualTreeHelper but hoping for a cleaner solution.

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Regards,

Comment: Do you know at design time which fields are required? Then just set the tab order for them using the designer.

Comment: I would probably set tabstop false to all the rest. Write a control that sits in the parent somewhere and iterates down through it's visual tree to set that property. Give it a dependency property ObservableCollection<propertyname> and bind that for required fields. Get the binding on each textbox and look at what it's binding to.

Comment: Hi, thanks for current feedback. Sorry I probably should have included that I need normal tabbing to work aswell, so for required tabbing I use a different shortcut, to still be decided.. I catch this with PreviewKeyDown and attempt to navigate to next required field.